# how to delete the found match from a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, match

i am trying to find out what values of list_a is present in list_b. When the match is found it is stored in Match variable. what i then try to do is to delete that specific index (in which the match was found) from list_b so that next if there is a duplicate value in list_a it will not match the same place as previously (but instead move on to the next place it finds a match). However, it seems that i cant get the index position value of list_b deleted (i have tried pop(), del and even remove) can anyone help?

```
def match_elements(list_a, list_b):
    match = []
    index = []
    index1 = 0
    EM = []

    for i in list_a:
    
        if i in list_b:
           match.append(i) #put matched material in match list
           index.append(list_b.index(i)) #grab the bom_index number of the match 
           index1 = list_b.index(i) #make index1 equal to the index number of the match
           del list_b[index1] #Delete the value on position index1
        

        return index,match

 Production = match_elements(listnwsm,listbom)
```

listnwsm holds following:
K500106P
K600053P
K500106P
F900022G
R900069G
C500017X
K200003P
F300048B
C900216B

listbom holds following: (actually holds thousands of numbers but this is for example.)
K500106P
C900383B
C900378B
C900388B
C900139X
C900459B
C900232X
K500106P
C900208B

output gives me:
13487 K500106P
13487 K500106P
how am I getting duplicate index values when the value at position 13487 should be deleted after it has been saved?

Comment: Can you give an example of listnwsm and listbom we can use? Also your coding needs indenting so people can easily copy/paste to troubleshoot

Comment: Hi @ScottRowley I updated it now. hopefully everything you asked for is there. if not, let me know. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Hey, may you simplify the question and give us a basic examples of input and desired outputs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the list.index('whatever you want to delete') method to get the index. Also, using the list.remove() method will do the thing as it will remove the first instance of the object in the list, so there is no reputation.

I did not understand the question entirely, but I guess this might have answered your question!

Comment: Hi @Dhruv, i already tried list.remove and get the same output.
My question is:
How do I delete the value of the list that corresponds to the index value of the match? it should be easy with list.remove as you say but it doesnt seem to work so something is wrong somewhere i just dont know what.

The reason i want to remove the matched value from the list is because i have duplicate values in both lists. if i dont remove the matched value, the duplicates from list_a will just keep matching with the same value from list_b instead of moving on to the next duplicate on the list.